# Cannot boot 14.04 after upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade

I get the following error message:

adevadm trigger is not permitted while udev is unconfigured.
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check root delay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat proc/modules; ls /dev)
Alert! /dev/disk/by_uuid/29a43722-5f26-49f6-bd5f-a8082b34466c does not exit.
Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)

Now, I am able to boot a live cd and then it's possible to see all the data on both my disks. I guess I have to repair the MBR, bu I am not sure how. 
Could anyone chime in?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there was an error while updating grub. I'd suggest trying a program like boot repair to see if that could fix it, or to backup your /home directory to another drive and do a fresh install of the version you wanted to upgrade to.

I've received that error before when updating Ubuntu on a usb hard drive, but I'd accidentally messed up the kernel, which required me to either manually fix it, or to do a fresh install. I went with the fresh install.

Hope this helps.

Also, if you have any logs of the original upgrade, please provide them, if possible.